# Open activity only for the first run

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a button in my first layout and I want when a user clicks on it, it shows another activity and then never shows the first activity.

I tried this :

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

if (isFirstRun) {
    //show start activity
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstLaunch.class));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt, because may be it won't hit the `getSharedPreferences()` line, and it just navigated to your New Activity `FirstLaunch`.

So I think it should be like,

```
if (isFirstRun) {
    //show start activity
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstLaunch.class));
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

So basically, before navigate to `FirstLaunch` Activity you have to save the state of `isFirstRun`in SharedPreferences.

Comment: this doesn't worked too, I want when user moved to another activity then my first activity not showing anymore